# EF Core 5 code-first computed column using Function

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core

What is the recommended approach to use functions within computed columns in EF Core 5.0?

We are using SQL Server and `Migrate()` to create and update the database.

For other purposes we had a `.sql` script that runs after database creation to take heed of creating functions and stored procedures.

The last migration inserts a computed column. Obviously we need this functions before adding the column but after creating schema. Our current solution is to add the functions as direct call `migrationBuider.Sql()`.

```
migrationBuilder.Sql(@"
                CREATE FUNCTION [sid].[hasCreditor]
                (
                    @contactId uniqueidentifier = null
                )
                RETURNS bit
                AS
                BEGIN   
                    DECLARE @result bit

                    IF(@contactId IS NULL)
                        SET @result = 0
                    ELSE
                    BEGIN
                        DECLARE @creditorCount int
                        SELECT @creditorCount = COUNT(*) FROM sid.Creditor WHERE ContactId = @contactId
                        SET @result = IIF(@creditorCount > 0, 1, 0)
                    END

                    RETURN @result
                END");

            migrationBuilder.AddColumn<bool>(
                name: "HasCreditor",
                schema: "sid",
                table: "Contact",
                type: "bit",
                nullable: true,
                computedColumnSql: "sid.hasCreditor(Id)");
```

The solution is working but if sometimes we need to consolidate the migrations and create a new base migration this part will be lost and we need to insert it manually again.

Is this the best way or is there a better approach for inserting functions? Also taking into account that we use a special SQL schema "sid".

Comment: I know this doesn't really answer your question, but the "ORMy" way of implementing your `hasCreditor` function would be to instead ensure that a navigation property exists between Contact and Creditor (on the `ContactId` foreign key) and then provide a derived property `bool Contact.HasCreditor => Creditors.Any()`. One of the downsides of using UDFs in this way that if they are invoked on a result set, that the UDF is invoked once per row.

Comment: Yep.  And calculated columns that read the database have bad code smell.

Comment: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5464/computed-columns-with-scalar-functions-sql-server-performance-issue/

Comment: And wouldn't you need to ensure this Navigation property to be included in the query or would ef do that automatically in this case?

Comment: As I read it, we should avoid using functions within computed columns at all if possible ...